# Mac OS : ld: library not found for -lglfw

Tags: macos, glfw

Building my project I get error:

```
ld: library not found for -lglfw
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I have installed `glfw`, via `brew install glfw`

```
brew list --versions | grep glfw
glfw 3.2.1

ls /usr/local/lib | grep glfw
libglfw.3.2.dylib
libglfw.3.dylib
libglfw.dylib


clang -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

MacOS : 10.14.1 (18B75)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like adding `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` to `~/.bash_profile` solved the problem, but I'm not sure if it's ellegant solution without side effects.